# Why my django app can't send email to registered user?

Tags: django, gmail, django-admin

I am trying to send user an email containing invitation/confirmation link.Command propmt is showing that email is being sent but user is not receiving any email.I am using my gmail account and also allows access by less secure apps on my account? What can be the possible errors?
Here is my settings file:-

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'someone@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

while my view uilizing it is as follows:-

```
@csrf_protect
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
            'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                    mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
            email.send()
            return JsonResponse({'success':True})
   else:
        form=SignupForm()
    return JsonResponse({'errors': [(k, v[0]) for k, v in form.errors.items()]})
```

Strange enough that my console is showing the email but the targeted user did not receive that email.

[image]

Comment: You can't tell the error by looking your code, how anyone supposed to know without seeing your settings file or how you sending email? Edit your question and add relevant details. (To downvoters, add atleast a comment so that the op will know the reason)

Comment: @BidhanMajhi Please check my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is this line of your configuration:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

> From [django documentation on
>   `console.EmailBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/email/#console-backend):
>
> > Instead of sending out real emails the console backend just writes the
> >     emails that would be sent to the standard output.

---

If you want to send out real emails choose a suitable backend. Since you seem to be attempting to use smtp you most likely want to use django's [`smtp.EmailBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/email/#smtp-backend) like this:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```